# calculate which timezones have a specific current local time on PHP

Tags: php, timezone

My application needs to send an email to all users at 6:00PM, on their local time.
The server is configured to GMT.
I have a function that is being called at the beginning of each hour.
How do I find out which timezones (PHP timezones) are now at 6:00PM?
(this way I can query the data base and find all users set to this timezone and send them the email).
Also is it possible to do it without iterating over the entire timezone array?
Thanks.

Comment: how is the time zone data stored for each user?

Comment: there is a mysql table for users. Each row is a different user and one of the columns contains the timezone info.

Comment: there are multiple ways to specify a time zone, can you be specific.

Comment: sure. I thought of using the php format. For example "America/New_York".

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer wasn't too great since daylight savings time precludes you from defining timezones in absolute offsets from GMT. Here's a better solution, assuming you're storing timezones in [one of these formats](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). This script should be run every 15 minutes on the quarter-hour.

```
// Target local time in hours (6:00 PM = 18:00)
$targetHour = 18;

// Get timestamp of nearest quarter-hour.
// (Assuming this is being run by cron on-the-quarter-hour by server time)
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$currentHourTimestamp = (round(time() / 900) * 900);

// Calculate offset in hours to target hour
$targetDateTime = new dateTime('@' . $currentHourTimestamp, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$targetDateTime->setTime($targetHour, 0, 0);
$targetOffset = $targetDateTime->getTimestamp() - $currentHourTimestamp;


// You can get this from the database with a 
// 'SELECT DISTINCT timezones FROM users' query or similar
$timezonesUsed = array('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Phoenix', 'Europe/Budapest', 'Europe/Dublin');

$matchingTimezones = array();
foreach($timezonesUsed as $localTimezone)
{
    // throws an Exception if timezone is not recognized
    $localDateTimezone = new DateTimeZone($localTimezone);
    $localOffset = $localDateTimezone->getOffset($targetDateTime);

    if($localOffset == $targetOffset)
    $matchingTimezones[] = $localTimezone;
}


// Now send emails to users in database with timezones in $matchingTimezones
```

Edit: Adapted script to use quarter-hours per Catcall's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I thought though of using the php datetimezone format (for example "America/New_York). Is there any way to use the dateformat functions to obtain the required result? Would your suggested method take care of DST?

Comment: @Avi, that's a good point with DST, since it's not just timezone-dependent (e.g., Arizona/Hawaii)... I'll play around with the DateTime functions and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: @Avi: Updated my answer. Good question, it takes some thought! I'd be interested to see if anyone know of a built-in "get all timezones with *n* offset to GMT" method, since that'd be more efficient, but for something like this running once per hour this should be OK.

Comment: It might make sense to store the timezones and their offsets. All that data is in a system table in PostgreSQL. Running `SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names` returns 567 rows.

Comment: @Catcall Yeah, that's a great solution if you're using PostgreSQL as your RDBMS, since it automatically updates the table values to handle DST changes. There's more to a timezone than *just* a +/- GMT offset and DST flag, though, and you'd have to add [some tedious logic](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_around_the_world) for that if you were working with a *static* table.

Comment: @Chris Hepner: You're probably right. You'll need to run your script more than once an hour though. Not all offsets from UTC are on the hour; some are on the quarter hours.

Comment: @Catcall Good call, didn't think of that. Thanks!